# Define $R$ to be a relation on integers such that $a\,R\,b$ if $|a-1| \leq |b-1|$. Is $R$ a partial order on $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: relations

How can I even prove this to be true?

Prove that $R$ is a partial order on integers.

Comment: Apply the definition of [Partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition) starting from the easy part: is $R$ *reflexive* ?

Comment: What have you attempted thus far? Also, write **\le** or **\leq** to generate $\leq$ and **\leqslant** to generate $\leqslant$. The words in bold are known as *commands* and are written with a \ in the beginning. To put them into action, add dollar signs at the start and end of each command, i.e. $\$\ldots\$$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thanks i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Apparantly $0R2\wedge 2R0$. Can this be true if $R$ is a partial order?